# How to optimize a query performance by re-reordering populate, sort, and limit

Tags: database, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query, nosql

Optimization needed for my Heroku app database queries: The MongoDB hosted by Mongolab contains 2 million documents (3,5 GB and increasing), now this single query takes 2,3 secs to complete on average and Heroku returns timeouts after 200 concurrent users are using the app.

How to optimize this query? Is the order of populate, sort and limit affecting to the performance, can these be ordered differently? The output should be same if limit 100 happens before populate, how can it be done in this code?

Mongolab says that the existing indexes are ok, so is there something to do for the code itself?

```
  findcustomermydataResults = async (
    league: ILeague,
    user: IUser,
    minwp: number,
    maxwp: number
  ): Promise<ImydataResult[]> => {
    try {
      const mydataResultsInRange = await mydataresult.find(
        {
          league: league._id,
          wp: { $gte: minwp, $lte: maxwp },
          user: { $ne: user._id },
        },
        { user: 1, id: 1, wp: 1, mydata: 1, time: 1, createdAt: 1 }
      )
        .populate({
          path: "user",
          select: ["displayName", "country", "cargo", "customId", "chea"],
        })
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .limit(100);
      this.debug(
        `findcustomermydataResults() - found: ${
          mydataResultsInRange.length
        } mydata results`
      );
      return mydataResultsInRange;
    } catch (err) {
      this.error(`findcustomermydataResults() - try catch error: ${err}`);
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the Index Hint to the query made it 100x faster

Answer (score 1):

Try moving populate to the end of the query. You already have the necessary data in order to sort by just doing the initial query. This way it should limit the populate lookup to just the expected 100 results increasing performance dramatically.

````js
  findcustomermydataResults = async (
    league: ILeague,
    user: IUser,
    minwp: number,
    maxwp: number
  ): Promise<ImydataResult[]> => {
    try {
      const mydataResultsInRange = await mydataresult.find(
        {
          league: league._id,
          wp: { $gte: minwp, $lte: maxwp },
          user: { $ne: user._id },
        },
        { user: 1, id: 1, wp: 1, mydata: 1, time: 1, createdAt: 1 }
      )
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .limit(100)
        .populate({
          path: "user",
          select: ["displayName", "country", "cargo", "customId", "chea"],
        });
      this.debug(
        `findcustomermydataResults() - found: ${
          mydataResultsInRange.length
        } mydata results`
      );
      return mydataResultsInRange;
    } catch (err) {
      this.error(`findcustomermydataResults() - try catch error: ${err}`);
      return null;
    }```
````

Comment: Thanks, made this change and so far there was no major change detected..